# Is it possible to add a notification message when a VPN gets connected?

Tags: 10.04, vpn, notification

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and I use to connect to a pptp VPN, everything works perfectly, when i start my VPN connection I can see that the connection is in progress from the NetworkManager icon, and I can see that the connection is on when the Network icon gets the small lock.

[image: notification area with network connection and vpn lock icon]

Is it possible to add a notification ballon, like the one I see when the network connection is estabilished?

[image: eth0 connection estabilished notification baloon]

P.s if the connection fail or is dropped, the notification cames out like this:
[image: vpn failed]

Comment: You probably should file your request as bug report for network manager.

Comment: @João Pinto ok, I do a bit more workaround and then I file it as a bug.

Comment: +1 for good question. It needs to be mention it is a bug. Something got forgotten in the network notification.

Comment: bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/712621

Comment: Looking at the bug now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like a hack but should work (works for me).

vpn-notify.py:

```
import gtk
import pynotify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def vpn_connection_handler(*args, **keywords):
    state = args[0].get('State',0)
    if state == 2:
        n = pynotify.Notification ("VPN", "Connection established")
        n.show()


pynotify.init ("icon-summary-body")


dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop()

system_bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
system_bus.add_signal_receiver(vpn_connection_handler,
    dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection",
    signal_name="PropertiesChanged")

gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

Run it with:

```
python vpn-notify.py
```

Establish the VPN connection.

Comment: it works! Now I have some more info to file the bug report.

Comment: Maybe you want to check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/351309/169736

Answer (score 0):

### Here is code which tells if you are connected to VPN or NOT.

```
**Note:** *IPv4 adress of the machine on VPN might change each time you connect to VPN.*

    import subprocess
    host = '**.***.***.***' 
    #IPv4 should be string ''
    #IPv4 Address (while connected to VPN in command prompt type: ipconfig",
    copy IPv4 Address digits and paste as "host = ", 
    #IPv4 Address. changes each time we freshly connect to VPN. )
    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe","-n","1","-w","1",host],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    if ('unreachable' in str(ping)) or ('timed' in str(ping)) or ('failure' in str(ping)):
        ping_chk = 0
    else:
        ping_chk = 1 

    if ping_chk == 1:
         print ("VPN Connected")
    else:
        print ("VPN Not Connected")
```