# Notification message when VPN gets disconnected

Tags: python, network-manager

This question is like [Is it possible to add a notification message when a VPN gets connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24604/is-it-possible-to-add-a-notification-message-when-a-vpn-gets-connected) .
The python script in the answer there (see below) works OK on 13.04, but it only notifies on making new connections, not when a VPN connection is disconnected, which is much more important since it can happen at any time.

Can someone please tweak the script for disconnections?

Alternatively, where is the network connection (for VPN) tray icon held in the file system,
so I can change it - the miniature padlock is so tiny it is barely visible. Reversed foreground/background colours would be better.

```
import gtk  
import pynotify  
import dbus  
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop  
def vpn_connection_handler(*args, **keywords):  
    state = args[0].get('State',0)  
    if state == 2:  
        n = pynotify.Notification ("VPN", "Connection established")  
        n.show()  
pynotify.init ("icon-summary-body")  
dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop()  
system_bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)  
system_bus.add_signal_receiver(vpn_connection_handler,  
    dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection",  
    signal_name="PropertiesChanged")  
gtk.gdk.threads_init()  
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple actually. You already know that you have to check `state` to see when the vpn is connected, so add a little print statement to see which value `state` is when you disconnect the vpn.

I get `4`, so just add an elif block:

```
    elif state == 4:  
        n = pynotify.Notification ("VPN", "Connection lost")  
        n.show()
```

however, I already get notifications from Network Manager itself, don't you?